# The electric field of conducting and non conducting sheets

Tags: electric-fields, gauss-law

When a non conducting sheet is charged , the electric field due to it is half the electric field due to a charged conducting sheet. How exactly do they differ? When we use gauss law using a Gaussian cylinder we should get similar results. Please explain.

Moreover in some books I have read that the electric field due to individual plates of capacitor is the same as of a non conducting sheet of charge? How is this possible as the plates are conductors themselves... Please explain.